# Create an IAM role with Terraform to access S3 bucket over EKS

Tags: amazon-s3, terraform, amazon-iam, amazon-eks

In my EKS app I have this minimal example to reproduce:

```js
        const tempCredentials = new aws.ChainableTemporaryCredentials({
            params: {
                RoleArn: 'some-other-arn',
            },
        });

        tempCredentials.get(console.error);

        console.log(tempCredentials.accessKeyId);
        console.log(tempCredentials.secretAccessKey);
```

I get the following error:
`AccessDenied: User: (eks-arn-role) is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: some-other-arn`

This is my terraform file:

```
# 0. Create another role that my app will assume
resource "aws_iam_role" "techdocs_iam_role" {
  name = var.techdocs_iam_role
  assume_role_policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17"
    Statement = [
      {
        Action = "sts:AssumeRole"
        Effect = "Allow"
        Sid    = ""
        Principal = {
          Service = "eks.amazonaws.com"
        }
      },
    ]
  })
}


# 1. My App should be able to AssumeRole only to 'some-other-arn' resource.
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "app_iam_policy" {
  statement {
    actions = [
      "sts:AssumeRole"
    ]

    resources = [
      "some-other-arn" # The role created in Step 0.
    ]
  }
}

# 2. Create S3 bucket
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "bucket" {
  bucket = var.techdocs_bucket_name
}

# 3. Create policy to S3 bucket
resource "aws_iam_policy" "policy" {
  name        = "policy"
  description = "Policy to access S3 bucket"
  policy = jsonencode({
    "Version" : "2012-10-17",
    "Statement" : [
      {
        "Effect" : "Allow",
        "Action" : ["s3:PutObject",
          "s3:GetObject",
          "s3:DeleteObjectVersion",
          "s3:ListBucket",
          "s3:DeleteObject",
        "s3:PutObjectAcl"],
        "Resource" : ["arn:aws:s3:::${var.techdocs_bucket_name}", "arn:aws:s3:::${var.techdocs_bucket_name}/*"]
      }
    ]
  })
}
```

Step 1 is working because I have the `AWS_` environment variables injected in EKS and the Web Identity Token File is created, but it can't assume the role created on Terraform.

I need to a create a new role that my EKS can assume the role to, and apply certain S3 actions either to that bucket or to that role.

thanks for the help!

Comment: You should not need to manually assume any role. As long as your SDK version is new enough, you can omit all credentials configuration and it will automatically detect and use IRSA.

Comment: Your trust policy looks incorrect for IRSA https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/iam-roles-for-service-accounts.html

Comment: Is this your cluster role, node role? Need a bit more info but as said above it's 99% chance that your trust policy is wrong based on the AWS error you're getting

Comment: If we disregard issues others have mentioned, referencing the role should not be too much of an issue. That could be done with `aws_iam_role.techdocs_iam_role.arn`.